# Erro @PostMapping @ManyToOne settando "usuario_id" spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou usando o Spring e o Hibernate em um dos aplicativos em que estou trabalhando e tenho um problema com o processamento de transações.

Preciso fazer um POST usando 2 entidades, a LancamentoEntity e UsuarioEntity, onde o lancamento possui o usuario_id. Quando tentei usar com o "optional = true" estava indo, tentando passar o id do UsuarioEntity para o lancamento.setIdUsuarioEntity() o erro no Postman é este:

```
Erro no método postLancamento(): Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
```

Chamada no Postman:

```
http://localhost:8080/postLancamento/2
```

Dados:

```
{
"descricao": "Teste sdad   adsuygh  dsahudashuasdhu  iadshuidashuidas    ",
"valor": 780 
}
```

Meu método na controller:

```
@PostMapping("/postLancamento/{usuario_id}")
public String postLancamento(@PathVariable(value = "usuario_id") Long usuario_id, @Valid @RequestBody LancamentoEntity lancamentoEntity,
    UsuarioEntity usuarioEntity) {
try {
    usuarioEntity = new UsuarioEntity();
    usuarioEntity.setId(usuario_id);
    usuarioRepository.save(usuarioEntity);
    // usuarioEntity.getId(); 
    lancamentoEntity = new LancamentoEntity();
    lancamentoEntity.setUsuarioEntity(usuarioEntity);
    lancamentoRepository.save(lancamentoEntity);
    return usuarioEntity.toString();
} catch (
Exception e) {
    return "Erro no método postLancamento(): " + e.getMessage();
}
}
```

LancamentoEntity:

```
  package com.webservice.msi.model;
@Entity
@Table(name = "lancamento")
public class LancamentoEntity implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;
@Column(name = "data_de_lancamento")
private LocalDateTime data_de_lancamento;
@Column
private String descricao;
@Column
private Float valor;
// @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
@ManyToOne( cascade =  CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
private UsuarioEntity usuario;
public LancamentoEntity() {
}
public LancamentoEntity(UsuarioEntity usuario, LocalDateTime data_de_lancamento, String descricao, Float valor) { 
this.usuario = usuario;
this.data_de_lancamento = data_de_lancamento;
this.descricao = descricao;
this.valor = valor;
}
public UsuarioEntity getUsuarioEntity() {
return usuario;
}
public void setUsuarioEntity(UsuarioEntity ue) {
this.usuario = ue;
  }
public LancamentoEntity(UsuarioEntity ueId) {
this.usuario = ueId;
}
public Long getId() {
return this.id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getDescricao() {
return this.descricao;
}
public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
this.descricao = descricao;
}
public Float getValor() {
return this.valor;
}
public void setValor(Float valor) {
this.valor = valor;
}
public LocalDateTime getData_de_lancamento() {
return this.data_de_lancamento;
}
public void setData_de_lancamento(LocalDateTime data_de_lancamento) {
this.data_de_lancamento = data_de_lancamento;
}
```

}

UsuarioEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class UsuarioEntity implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Size(max = 30)
private String nome;
@NotBlank(message = "Por favor, insira um e-mail")
@Size(max = 50)
private String email;
@Size(max = 50)
private String senha;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private ContaEntity conta;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<LancamentoEntity> lancamentos;
public UsuarioEntity() {
}
public UsuarioEntity(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}
public UsuarioEntity(String nome, String email, String senha) {
this.nome = nome;
this.email = email;
this.senha = senha;
}
public UsuarioEntity(String nome, String email, String senha, ContaEntity contaEntity) {
this.nome = nome;
this.email = email;
this.senha = senha;
this.conta = contaEntity;
}
public Long getId() {
return this.id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getNome() {
return this.nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
this.nome = nome;
}
public String getEmail() {
return this.email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}
public String getSenha() {
return this.senha;
}
public void setSenha(String senha) {
this.senha = senha;
}
public List<LancamentoEntity> getLancamento() {
return lancamentos;
}
public void setLancamento(List<LancamentoEntity> lancamentos) {
this.lancamentos = lancamentos;
}
public ContaEntity getIdContaUsuario() {
return this.conta;
}
public void setIdContaUsuario(ContaEntity contaEntity) {
this.conta = contaEntity;
}
public String toString() {
return "{" + " id='" + getId() + "'" + ", name='" + getNome() + "'" + ", lastName='" + getSenha() + "'"
    + ", email='" + getEmail() + "'" + ", conta ='" + getIdContaUsuario() + "'" + "}";
}
}
```

O erro no terminal pelo que estou percebendo é que não estou passando corretamente apenas o UsuarioEntity.getId():

```
Completed initialization in 6 ms Hibernate: select usuarioent0_.id as id1_2_1_, usuarioent0_.conta_id as conta_id5_2_1_, usuarioent0_.email as email2_2_1_, usuarioent0_.nome as nome3_2_1_, usuarioent0_.senha as senha4_2_1_, lancamento1_.usuario_id as usuario_5_1_3_, lancamento1_.id as id1_1_3_, lancamento1_.id as id1_1_0_, lancamento1_.data_de_lancamento as data_de_2_1_0_, lancamento1_.descricao as descrica3_1_0_, lancamento1_.usuario_id as usuario_5_1_0_, lancamento1_.valor as valor4_1_0_ from usuario usuarioent0_ left outer join lancamento lancamento1_ on usuarioent0_.id=lancamento1_.usuario_id where usuarioent0_.id=?
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código todo das suas classes Entity?

Comment: @mbissonho editei com as Entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em seu exemplo, você inicializa os objetos `lancamentoEntity` e `usuarioEntity` no seu método.

Primeiramente, o `usuarioEntity` não é necessário na assinatura do método.
O segundo paço é não reinicializar o objeto `lancamentoEntity` pois você o passa no parâmetro:

```
    @PostMapping("/postLancamento/{usuario_id}")
    public String postLancamento(@PathVariable(value = "usuario_id") Long usuarioId, @Valid @RequestBody LancamentoEntity lancamentoEntity) {
        try {
            UsuarioEntity usuarioEntity = usuarioRepository.findByUsuarioId(usuarioId);

            lancamentoEntity.setUsuarioEntity(usuarioEntity);
            lancamentoRepository.save(lancamentoEntity);
            return usuarioEntity.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Erro no método postLancamento(): " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creio que meu UsuarioRepository está errado, olha como está: 
Repository
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<UsuarioEntity, Long> {

}

Olha o erro:
The method findByUsuarioId(Long) is undefined for the type UsuarioRepositoryJava(67108964)

Aproveitando, o LancamentoRepository:
Repository
public interface LancamentoRepository extends JpaRepository<LancamentoEntity, Long> {

}

Comment: Foi só um exemplo, vc pode user findyById(). Como seu `id` já é um `@Id`, o repositório vai criar o método para você.

Comment: Consegui assim:             

Optional<UsuarioEntity> optional = usuarioRepository.findById(usuarioId);
            UsuarioEntity usuarioEntity = optional.get();

Comment: Você pode fazer isso em uma linha também com `.findById(usuarioId)                                   .orElseThrow(() -> NofFoundException);`. com Optional é sempre bom verificar se existe ou não, pois via sua API pode existir um caso que o usuarioId não é valido (não está no banco)